# USB to RF bridge: Kettler Ergorace bike

Tags: usb, rf

I own a Kettler Ergorace indoor bike. It's possible to create exercises using the USB interface. When plugged into a PC, it is shown as a virtual com port ([SiLabs CP2102](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/CP2102-9.pdf))

I would like to control it from my Android tablet (over Bluetooth, Wi-Fi or any RF)

My project is to build a simple (and cheap) wireless bridge from this USB port to my tablet. First idea would be to use a Raspberry Pi + Wi-Fi dongle + some kind of pass through program. Is there a cheaper solution ?

Comment: What about using an USB-to-wifi converter that makes a virtual USB port?

Comment: Something like a pi/beaglebon/yun/hacked router would do it.  Or your could desolder the CP2102 (or maybe resistors leading to it?) and get at the serial lines behind it.  You could also probably connect it with an OTG adapter cable to many (but not all) Android phones or tablets.

Comment: As far as I know cp2102 is not a USB host. I don't think it's possible to use a standard usb wifi dongle. What is an otg adapter ? My tablet (tf101) has no support for USB host mode. Android supports cp2102?

Comment: @Emmanuel Candus Wifi dongle is not what i meant. There are devices like [this](http://silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/sx-ds-3000wn/), a remote USB host controller. Not sure about Android compatibility.

Comment: I've been facing exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution? In this case, could you please share it (step by step please). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to butcher your device, you can find traces that go to the CP1202 and connect one of the many bluetooth-to-serial adapters. Make sure to find one which is pre-programmed accordingly and doesn't rely on the host device that it's connected to initializing it with AT commands every time, else you will be stuck. I don't remember which is suitable for this purpose, but i recall i have seen some.

As an alternative to Pi in the same vein, but smaller power and form-factor, but without display output (hey, you're not making a PC), you may want to consider Arietta G25 and its sibling, CoreTech WiFiG25.

If you were aiming for the cheapest possible hardware, it might be PIC32MX210, some of them have USB Host and cost <4$. To that, you connect some serial Bluetooth. I won't be able to tell you how easy or hard it will be to program, because you might have to do the USB CDC support yourself. In the same vein, other microcontrollers would be in the PIC24 series and AT32UC3B.

Comment: Arietta G25 is a very good choice. CP2102 Driver is already implemented, and form factor is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If some people are interested, I wrote some come using Raspberry Pi zero and NodeJS
https://github.com/360manu/kettlerUSB2BLE

it was easier (for me) to implement this system with a complete system